# GeoServer: using the CSS extension style the "Separate geometry columns"

Tags: geoserver

I'm using the GeoServer documentation for "Styling mixed geometry types" and exactle this part of it [Separate geometry columns](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/tipstricks/mixed-geometries.html#separate-geometry-columns).

How can I repeat this SLD style using the CSS extension?

```
<PolygonSymbolizer>
    <Geometry><ogc:PropertyName>polygon</ogc:PropertyName></Geometry>
</PolygonSymbolizer>
```

I tried to use the ": nth-..." pseudo selector but had no success.

Maybe there are other selectors which I can use for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Check the property listing for CSS:
https://docs.geoserver.org/2.23.x/en/user/styling/css/properties.html

The properties you are looking for are called `mark-geometry`, `stroke-geometry`, `fill-geometry` and so on.

Comment: Hey Andrea! Thanks for your help. I'm struggling with using one style file for different column types. I have 2 point columns, 2 polygon columns, and 1 line column. I had issues with "mark-geometry", ...  while using them in one style.